# Image does not display within a div

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to create a slideshow in my angular app. I'm unable to display the images in the html code.

I created a separate component for the slideshow (carousel.component). In the app component, i've a navbar and beneath the navbar, i created a container. Within this container, I've placed my carousel component where I'm expecting my slideshow to appear.

Edit: I've reproduced the issue in stackblitz. Here's the link:
https://angular-st4auy.stackblitz.io/

**app.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar> 
<div class="container">
  <app-carousel></app-carousel>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
 .container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
```

carousel.component.html

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide" *ngFor="let image of images">
      <img [src]="image" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

carousel.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.css']
})
export class CarouselComponent {

 images = [
   'http://localhost:4200/assets/images/img1.jpeg',
   'http://localhost:4200/assets/images/img2.jpeg',
   'http://localhost:4200/assets/images/img3.jpeg'
 ];


  constructor() {}
  currentIndex = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex + 1) % this.images.length;
    }, 5000); // change image every 5 seconds
  }

  getSlideClasses(index) {
    const classes = ['slide'];
    if (index === this.currentIndex) {
      classes.push('active');
    }
    return classes;
  }
 
}
```

carousel.component.css

```
.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  /* height: calc(100vh - 50px); subtract the height of your navbar */
  height:100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Tried giving a fixed height and checked in developer tools. I can see the divs and the images are also accessible in the developer tool but can't seem to find why the images are not being displayed.

Comment: Without a minimal reproducible example it's unlikely to get a response. You can read about how to create it here: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget add the classes to your slide.
You can use

```
  <div class="slide" [class.active]="i==currentIndex" 
          *ngFor="let image of images;let i=index">
```

or your function getSlideClasses

```
  <div [class]="getSlideClasses(i)"
          *ngFor="let image of images;let i=index">
```